# Sending many types at the same time with a socket

Tags: java, sockets, network-programming, serversocket

I want to send a single stream of data corresponding to a couple of different types (say for simplicity one float and one int) from a Socket to another socket (created from a ServerSocket accept()). However, I am not sure what the best way to achieve this is. If I want to use readInt() or readFloat() it seems that I need to send them separately, and I guess that would not be ideal (but please correct me if I am wrong).

The code would start by doing the following (where say the float will be stored in the first 4 bytes in b, and the int will be stored in the last 4 bytes in b)

```
ServerSocket socket = new ServerSocket(port);
in=new DataInputStream(socket.accept().getInputStream());

byte[] b = new byte[8];
in.read(b);
```

So far so good, but I would now like to convert only the first four bytes to a float and the last four bytes to an int. I could do something like

```
float myFloat = ByteBuffer.wrap(b).getFloat();
```

to get the float, but how do I get the int? In C++ I would just pass the reference to the fifth element in b, but as I understand it this is not possible in java. Of course I could use some library to create a new array from the last four elements of b, but that seems a bit overkill no? or is that the only way?

Any other suggestions on sending many different types at the same time over a socket are greatly appreciated.

Comment: why can't you use a separator (say newline) between each value you sending?

Comment: Can you please expand on this? It sounds like you want me to send it as a string, but I don't want to send more data than necessary (ie I only want to send 8 bytes, if possible).

Comment: if you already know the input is going to be 4 bytes int and 4 bytes float, then you can simply ready bytes by bytes and use the first 4 for your int and the next 4 for your float, if you need to send several values together, you need a seperator , just you know a new line is a single byte(value 10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to send a single stream of data [...] from a Socket to a ServerSocket

Sorry to be nitpicky, but you can't do that.  A `ServerSocket` is a mechanism for accepting connection requests and establishing the local end of a socket-based communication channel.  That local end, once established, is represented by a `Socket`, so what you seem to want to do is send data from `Socket` to *`Socket`*.

But your question seems mainly to be about sending mixed data over the communication channel.  In that case, the first question to consider is how the receiver knows what type to attempt to read at any given point.  This boils down to having an application-layer communication protocol between the communicating parties.  That doesn't have to be formal or grandiose; in your example, there seems to be a shared understanding that the data will be sent as a 32-bit binary `float` followed by a 32-bit binary `int`.  That's a protocol.

> If I want to use readInt() or readFloat() it seems that I need to send them separately, and I guess that would not be ideal

I don't see what you mean.  Yes, you do need to know which data are `int`s and which are `float`s, but that does not distinguish use of `DataInputStream.readInt()` and `DataInputStream.readFloat()` from any other mechanism.

For each datum you transmit, you have two basic alternatives:

1. count on the receiver to rely on some prior agreement or assumption to determine how to interpret that datum (possibly extending to recognizing the boundaries of its on-the-wire representation), or
2. along with the datum, transmit metadata that the receiver will use to interpret the datum as intended.

Of course, (2) can be viewed as a special case of (1).

If a message will always consist of one float followed by one int, then I don't see anything wrong with the sender using

```
myDataOutputStream.writeFloat(f);
myDataOutputStream.writeInt(i);
```

and the receiver handling that via

```
myDataInputStream.readFloat(f);
myDataInputStream.readInt(i);
```

Indeed, for that simple case, I think that's a pretty good choice.

More generally, however, there are many, many other considerations in choosing or designing a communication protocol.  A general discussion of that topic would be far too broad for this venue.

Comment: Thanks, yes I meant sending data between two sockets. And yes I am considering a situation where I know that the data should come in this particular format. My concern was that if I first did writeFloat() and then writeInt(), the socket would send the two data separately, but maybe that is not the case? Or maybe the concept of "sending them at the same time" is not even a well defined question? Sorry I am very new to networking.

Comment: @JonathanLindgren, a communication channel whose endpoints are represented by sockets is just a sequence of bytes.  `writeFloat()` and `writeInt()` will each write some bytes to that channel, and `readFloat()` and `readInt()` will each read the appropriate number of bytes.  In practice, all eight bytes and perhaps more are likely to be sent in the same network packet, but you've not presented any reason to think that that would actually matter in this case.  Those details are largely transparent at the socket level.

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Serializable` wrapper class for storing values of different types and `ObjectInputStream` & `ObjectOutputStream` for reading & writing the class instance seems to be the best way to achieve this. [Here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/991180/Java-Sockets-and-Serialization) and [here](http://www.coderpanda.com/java-socket-programming-transferring-of-java-objects-through-sockets/) are good references.

Comment: This requires us to create a whole new class only to store two variables, seems a bit unnecessary? If I send that whole class, will it really only be 8 bytes?

Comment: No, it won't be 8 bytes. If you have 8 bytes constraint, then you can use writeFloat, writeInt & readFloat, readInt sequentially. However, if you don't have such constraint then this is a good way to approach the problem since you can extend & modify it easily via changing the class.

Comment: Not only will using Java serialization involve sending more than 8 bytes, it will involve sending *much* more than 8.  Additionally, sender and receiver will both need to have definitions of the relevant class.  You can make it work, at least if both ends are written in Java, but I'm not a big fan of serialization as a general communication protocol.